# TypeError: context must be a dict rather than HttpResponseRedirect

Tags: django

I'm using `Django 2.0` and have been trying to redirect user to other view from `get_context_data`

my url pattern is

mainapp.urls

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('learn/', include('learn.urls', namespace='learn')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

app.url

```
app_name = 'learn'
urlpatterns = [
    path('success/<course_learn_id>/<session>', LearnSuccess.as_view(), name='success'),
]
```

and `LearnSuccess` view

```
class LearnQuestion(FormView):
    form_class = SessionForm
    template_name = 'learn/learn_question.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(LearnQuestion, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        course_learn = CourseLearn.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['course_learn_id'])

        session = self.request.GET['session']
        question, question_type, options, complete = CourseLearn.objects.get_next_question(course_learn, session)

        if complete:
            return redirect('learn:success', course_learn_id=course_learn.pk, session=session)

        context['complete'] = complete
        context['question'] = question
        context['question_type'] = context_type
        context['options'] = options
        context['session'] = session

        return context

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(self.__class__, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

I'm using Ajax to render this view and want to redirect user when `complete` is `True`

But this is giving error as

```
TypeError: context must be a dict rather than HttpResponseRedirect.
```

I even tried `return reverse()` but it is also giving error.

Trying

```
return redirect('learn:success', kwargs={'course_learn_id':course_learn.pk, 'session':session})
```

gives error

```
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'success' with keyword arguments 
'{'kwargs': {'course_learn_id': UUID('374ccfcd-37b5-40d3-8673-01ca111f42bc'), 'session': '1524972935'}}' not found. 
1 pattern(s) tried: ['learn\\/success\\/(?P<course_learn_id>[^/]+)\\/(?P<session>[^/]+)$']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by using `render_to_response`. For those who may need it, add a function inside the class

```
def render_to_response(self, context, **response_kwargs):
    if context['complete']:
        return redirect(reverse('learn:success',
                        kwargs={
                            'course_learn_id': context['course_learn'].pk,
                            'session': context['session']
                        }))
    return super(LearnQuestion, self).render_to_response(context, **response_kwargs)
```

and from `get_context_data()` send the context data

```
if complete:
    context['complete'] = complete
    context['course_learn'] = course_learn
    context['session'] = session

    return context
```

Comment: You should be using `get()` as outlined by @solarissmoke. You can access your context by calling `context = self.get_context_data()` at the top of the method then use the same logic to redirect.

Comment: I got **__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pk'**

Answer (score 10):

`get_context_data()` is supposed to be for you to add additional context to the template before it is rendered. It is **not** for doing other view-level logic.

You are trying to return a redirect response object from there, which is invalid - the return value of `get_context_data()` can only be a dictionary.

The logic you are currently trying to perform here should instead be in your view's `get()` method, something like:

```
def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
    course_learn = CourseLearn.objects.get(pk=kwargs['course_learn_id'])
    session = self.request.GET['session']
    question, question_type, options, complete = CourseLearn.objects.get_next_question(course_learn, session)

    if complete:
        return redirect('learn:success', course_learn_id=course_learn.pk, session=session)

    return super().get(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: But I'm also setting `complete` in context if it is `false`. I sliced it from question to make to short. Added context data in question